# Sonata Admin Use Custom Route in child list

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have an admin class Order that i used of 2 ways :

- A classic list
- Included in a tab in an other Entity Contact.

I created a custom route in my Order Admin with a Custom Action :

```
protected function configureRoutes(\Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection $collection)
{

    $collection->add('sendOrderByMail', '{orderNumber}/sendOrderByMail');

}
```

And in my list template i have :

```
 <a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('sendOrderByMail', {'orderNumber': object}) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default view_link"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send</a>
```

This is it's ok in my first case (A classic list), but in my ContactAdmin where i included the OrderAdmin in child i have this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("unable to find the route acme_appli.admin.contact|acme_appli.admin.order.sendOrderByMail") in AcmeAppliBundle:Admin/Order:list_order.html.twig at line 11.

I don't know how to make this route ok.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to defining the route for your new action, have you created a handler for it in your Controller (`sendOrderByMailAction`)?

Comment: I use the OrderAdminController created with my OrderAdmin class.

Comment: Try $admin->generateObjectUrl($name, $object, array $parameters = array(), $absolute = false);

Comment: $name can take one of this values: edit, create, list, delete. Depends of the url you want to generate

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to my cache.
Now it's ok because i empty this.